# Change background with javascript if child div is present

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, joomla

I need to change a background image of a parent div (content-indent) when child div (ezblog-head) is present. I've found lots of answers on the web. But I can't seem to get any of them to work.

The actual index.php page looks like this: (The site is built with Joomla)

```
<div class="content-indent">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

That loads in the browser as:

```
<div class="content-indent">
    <!-- bunch of other stuff -->
    <div id="ezblog-head>
        <!-- more stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript I'm using on my index page (It's not working)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('#ezblog-head')[0]){
      <style>
       .content-indent {background: #0f0;}
      </style>
    }
</script>`
```

I have also tried this (to no avail):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("ezblog-head")) { 
        document.getElementByClass('content-indent').style.background ='#0f0'
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you executing your javascript after the browser has rendered the DOM objects?  If not, then JS won't be able to find them.

Comment: You cannot insert a style tag in the middle of a JavaScript block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `ezblog-head` is an ID (assuming there will only be one in the page) you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ezblogHead = document.getElementById('ezblog-head');
if (ezblogHead){
    // ezblog-head exists on the page. Now, grab it's parent (content-indent)
    // and apply the bakground styling you prefer.
    ezblogHead.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
    // alternatively, if you wanted an image:
    //ezblogHead.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/path/to/background.jpg)';
}
</script>
```

Just make sure this is listed *after* the element has been rendered to the page, otherwise you're going to need to get in to binding the above to a DOMReady event.

Comment: That Was It! Thank you so much! Thank you everyone for your answers. I spent way too much time beating my head against the wall on this one. and this was the easiest answer for my tiny-brain to understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the style tags, use jQuery `.css()`. Note that this is using jQuery and not plain javascript so you'll also have to have a reference to jQuery prior to this script block.

```
if ($('#ezblog-head')) {
     $('.content-indent').css({'background': '#0f0'});
}
```

Comment: Given the `.content-indent>#ezblog-head` relationship, I would refer to the parent using `$('#exblog-head').parent().css(...)`, otherwise any other `.content-indent` elements on the page will be altered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your last sans-jquery example is almost there, but you'd want to use *getElementsByClassName('content-indent')[0]* (note the plural nature)

Easier still would be to use querySelector:

```
// change background of parent div (content-indent) when child div (ezblog-head) is present
if (document.querySelector('#ezblog-head')) {
  document.querySelector('.content-indent').style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
}
```

As noted elsewhere, make sure you're running the code after the dom is loaded, ie:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // do stuff here, the DOM is ready
});
```

Comment: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) has a lot of browser version limitations, however.

Comment: caniuse shows pretty much all modern browsers support it (including IE8+): http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Comment: Agreed, however it depends on target audience. I guess I'm scarred because I'm still supporting IE6 (corporate environment). If you have no worry of a visitor using IE<8, then it should be fine.